# Prove $\Bbb{N}$ is infinite from Peano axioms

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, axioms, peano-axioms

Let there be a set $\Bbb{N}$ defined by these 3 axioms:

There exists a set $\Bbb{N}$ such that $1\in \Bbb{N}$ and a function $s:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$ satisfying these properties:

$$\not\exists n\in\Bbb{N}:s(n)=1 \tag{i}$$
$$s \text{ is injective} \tag{ii}$$
$$\text{Let  $G\subseteq\Bbb{N}$ be a set. Suppose  $1\in G$.Then if $g\in G\Rightarrow s(g)\in G$ holds, then $G=\Bbb{N}$}\tag{iii}$$
What I am looking for is to prove that $\Bbb{N}$ is in fact infinite. In the book "The Real Numbers and Real Analysis" from E.D.Bloch there is following "explanation" given.

Suppose $\Bbb{N}$ is finite. $\Bbb{N}=\{1,p\}$.

Let $s:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$ be defined as follows: $s(1)=p,s(p)=p$. We see that in this case our triplet $(\Bbb{N},1,s)$ doesn't satisfy ii).

Let $s:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$ be defined in other way: $s(1)=p, s(p)=1$. In this case, the triplet $(\Bbb{N},1,s)$ doesn't satisfy i).

This "proof" seems very incomplete to me. Can i actually assume without loss of generality that if $\Bbb{N}$ is finite, then it has only 2 elements? It seems clear that if $s$ must be an injection and $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}:s(n)\neq1$. Then, if $\Bbb{N}$ had finite amount of elements, say $n$, we must always have "some next element to point the $s(n)$ to", but I would like a rigorous mathematical proof of that.

Comment: What is the definition of "finite" in the book mentioned?

Comment: Well, I've taken this part out of the context. First, there are these three axioms stated and the author doesn't even talk about "a proof" he just gives this explanation, that $\Bbb{N}$ is infinite. I think we can define a "finite set" being set such that the number of its elements is a counting number, such as $23,15,160...$

Comment: So would this mean that $A$ is finite iff there is some $n$ and some bijection $\alpha:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to A$?

Comment: Yes, that could be it.

Comment: You can't prove what isn't defined.  And "finite" and "infinite" are not defined.  The argument is that nothing that satisfies our *intuition* of the meaning finite, can satisfy these three axioms.  If $S$ has two elements and satisfies these axioms then $s$ must have a third element.  And if $S$ has three elements it must have a fourth... "and so on".  There's really no point in doing a proof because we are proving something about a formal definition against an informal version of ...*itself*.  Very circular. ... to be concluded...

Comment: Whereas a formal definition of finite and infinite will actuall be defined *in terms* of $\mathbb N$ and so $\mathbb N$ will be infinite by definition.

Comment: I can define "finiteness" as follows: Set $A$ is finite if there exists a bijection $f:\{1,2,\cdots,n\}\rightarrow A$. And "infiniteness" as follows: Set $A$ is infinite if it's not infinite. (Or perhaps, the function can be $f:A\rightarrow \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$)

Comment: But what seems really weird, that in my definition, we don't know what the $n$ is. So is it correct to talk about $\Bbb{N}$ being "infinite" (intuitively), because it's how it's constructed from the axiom?. Then, after we have constructed the set $\Bbb{N}$, we define a set to be finite or infinite if there exist bijection... blahblahblah...?

Comment: "So is it correct to talk about N being "infinite" (intuitively), because it's how it's constructed from the axiom?"  Well, no we can't which is why he doesn't bother at this point.  In the next 25 pages he defines the integers and the operations of  addition and *then* proves that if $s$ is defined to be function $s(n)=n+1$ then $s$ satisfies the axioms.  I think at this point we can define finite is any set bijective to $\{1,2,3...n\}$ and it can be proven that injective $f:N\to G$ exist if and only if G is not finite.

Comment: Ookkay, well, but the axioms do not say anything about $s$ right? Only that it's injective. What if $s(n)=n+2$...$n+3$... That's also an injection, isn't it? But wait.. do we know, what $2,3,...$ is? This is getting hilarious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of your book shows the method to prove $\mathbb N$ is infinite. With more detail, you should suppose $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$ and get a contradiction simply as follows: by (i) theres is no $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $s(m)=1$. So that, $1\notin\operatorname{im} s \subseteq \mathbb N$. Hence, you have to find an injection from a set with $n$ elemenets into a set with at most $n-1$ elements, which is impossible. The concluison is that if $\mathbb N$ is finite axiom (ii) is violated.

Answer (score 1):

He's doing a proof by induction.

That $1 \in \mathbb N$ means $\{1\}\subset \mathbb N$. And $s:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ says that $s(1)$ exists.

Axiom a: says $s(1)\ne 1$.  Let's label this as $p_1=s(1)$. So $\{1, p_1\} \subset \mathbb N$ and $\{1\}\subsetneq \mathbb N$..

Now $s(p_1)$ must exist.  But Axiom a: says $s(p_1) \ne 1$ and Axiom b: says $s(p_1) \ne p_1$.  Let's label this as $p_2$.  So $\{1,p_1,p_2\} \subset \mathbb N$ and $\{1,p_1\}\subsetneq \mathbb N$.

Propostion:  For any $n$ in... well, for any number that we can count [!!!] there is $N_k\subsetneq \mathbb N$ where $N_k =\{1,p_1=s(1), p_2=s(p_2), ... p_k=s(p_{k-1})\}$.  And as $N_k\subsetneq \mathbb N$ then $\mathbb N$ must have at least as many elements as $N_k$ which has $k$ elements and therefore $\mathbb N$ can not have any finite number of elements.

Pf:  By axiom b:  $s(p_k)\not \in N_k$.

So that's that.

But.... it's circularly pointless to call this a formal proof.  This axiom declares the natural numbers exists so how can I *use* them in an induction proof.

And the word "infinite" hasn't been well defined.

But it does show us that that natural numbers behave with the properties that an infinite set ought to.  And further if we define a set $G$ as "infinite" if there exists an injective $f:\mathbb N \to G$, then that will be a valid definition.  (I think.  We still don't have  a definition for "finite" and if we define "finite" as such an injection does not exist it might be hard to prove that to mean what ... we think it means.  We *can* do it, but it's not as straightforward as we'd like.)